# How to call c functions from PHP?

Tags: php, c, webserver, native, server-side-scripting

I am new to PHP Script. I was trying to call C functions from PHP. I was wondering how to call c functions from PHP. So please anyone can tell me,

1. How to call c functions from PHP?
2. Any other server side script's are there for call native functions?

Comment: you can run exe files from php but can not call C native functions from it.